# Mcrypt in Red Hat Enterprise

Tags: mcrypt

I'm working at a large organization, where the servers are managed by an IT department. I want to migrate some websites to Craft and asked the IT department to install Craft on a server. The IT department tells me that Mcrypt is not supported by RedHat Enterprise/PHP5.6, so Craft can't be installed

I'm not familiar with server software, are they right? And is it easy to add Mcrypt?

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what version of RHEL they're running, but it could certainly be added.  Whether your IT department will support it or if that breaks some support contract your company has with RH is another question all-together.

FWIW, Craft 3/Yii 2 has done away with mcrypt in favor of OpenSSL, so it's not an issue there.